# Tensorflow session not executing function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow placeholder in order to do a calculation however Tensorflow tells me that I have an initialization error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

al = np.array([2.5, 0.0, 2, 8],dtype=float)
bl = np.array([3, -0.5, 2, 7],dtype=float)

sess = tf.Session()

a = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32')
b = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32')


c = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)
d = sess.run(c, {a: al, b:bl } )
```

I cannot see where my mistake is. The error message is:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value mean_squared_error/count
     [[Node: mean_squared_error/count/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@mean_squared_error/AssignAdd_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](mean_squared_error/count)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise the variables that `tf.metrics.mean_squared_error` uses:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32')
b = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32')
c = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)
sess = tf.Session()
# Initialise the local variables
init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_local)
# Initialise the global variables (not really needed here)
# But you'll probably need it in the future when using tensorflow:
init_global = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_global)

al = np.array([2.5, 0.0, 2, 8],dtype=float)
bl = np.array([3, -0.5, 2, 7],dtype=float)
d = sess.run(c, {a: al, b:bl } )
```

Alternatively, in this case, you can use `tf.losses.mean_squared_error`.

I would check out [tensorflows programmers guide on variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) to get a better hold of these things :)

Comment: Thank you. But how did you know that `tf.metrics.mean_squared_error` used local variables? I have also noticed that if I use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` on its own here I get the same error but if I use `tf.local_variables_initializer()` on its own the issue is resolved.

Comment: @ImranRashid it wouldn't make sense to use variables that could be saved and restored internally in `tf.metrics.mean_squared_error`, so when it said that a variable inside there (count) was uninitialized then it was a fair chance it was local and not global. (Local variables won't get saved by a saver).

Comment: @ImranRashid It also says in [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_squared_error): "
The mean_squared_error function creates two local variables, `total` and `count` that are used to compute the mean squared error"

Answer (score 1):

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value mean_squared_error/count

The value `count` from the above error, is one of the local variable [`metrics.mean_squared_error`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_squared_error) uses to calculate MSE (the other is `count`). So you need to initialize the local variables using:

```
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay. This worked as well but how did you know to use `local_variables_initializer` instead of `global_variables_initializer`?

Comment: You dont need global_variables_initializer, the error is regarding local variables, i have added the link in my answer, there you can find the details of the two local variables.